# setX, setTranslationX, setLeft, LayoutParam.leftMargin, Matrix.. What's the difference

Tags: android

Another questions about setting position of a view. If you want to move a view around then you can do **setX**, **setTranslationX**, **setLeft** or **LayoutParam.leftMargin**
Offcourse there is also overriding the onDraw method and using **Matrix/Bitmap/Canvas** operation.

I was wondering what's the difference. Do they all ultimetly adjust the same value which is x coordinate of the view? 
It would be good to have it all in one post for future readers as well

So far I know,

- LayoutParam.LeftMargin:  is available for all API (specific under Api
  8)
- SetTranslation: Difference between original left bound of the view and the new leftbound. Though I heard maybe it is not persistent?

Anyone can shed light on the differences and if they impact different properties or the same property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the main difference between setLeft and `setX()` is that `setLeft()` is relative to its parent view, where `setX()` just sets the position relative to the whole screen, which is the same as `setTranslationX()`.

In `setLeft()` terms it means that the layout system can change its layout position.  For example if we would use setLeft while scrolling through a RecyclerView the system would change its position accordingly, so the proper use in this case would be `setX()`.